# Magento 1.9, Modify the existing Label under Category

Tags: magento-1.9, categories, label

i want to edit/Modify the labels under Category in Magento 1.9 Back-end.

here is the image for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are Labels for Attributes of catalog/category model.
You can edit them via Setup script or directly in the database.

**This will give you a complete overview of category attributes**:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = 3
```

Labels are stored in field `frontend_label`

> I honestly have no clue why someone would want to change those labels.
>   If your goal is to translate them, then this is a wrong approach. For
>   translation use locale files instead.

Comment: i also wants to know how we can change the Positions of Label ? means re-arrange them according to my requirements.